# LoopTools: Circle Modifier just mangles my mesh

Tags: modeling, loop

I have a very straightfoward area that I need to turn a mesh into a *Circle* using **LoopTools**.

Here is the area on the mesh and the before and after:
[image]

No matter how I configure those axis-locks and checkboxes, the result is just another variety of wrong. Notes:

- I've visited a number of other threads on BSE but have yet to find what I'd call a solution to this problem.
- I have restarted Blender, just because that's been a factor in the past
- The mesh itself is very basic. It's just a cube that I extracted into the floor of a building. I'm just going around doing external modeling on it.
- Cannot stress enough the basic nature of this build. I'm a noob and I'm doing a bunch of straightforward loop-cutting.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes it doesn't work, I don't know why, but you can try an alternative: alt shift S (To Sphere) and drag

Comment: Okay, I tried that. It's slightly better, but still not what I'd call smooth. Perhaps there's some other method to create smooth circles from a bunch of vertexes..

Comment: I don't know what you mean, if you drag several times you have a perfect circle, like with the LoopTools Circle... of course it is not a "smooth" circle because it has a limited amount of vertices, but if you use Subdivision Surface, 12 vertices is largely enough

Comment: I've subdivided the plane to a value of 12. This is what it looks like when I attempt that: https://i.ibb.co/xHP6zn3/DEFORM-2020-09-15.png - To be clear, this works just fine on a cube, just not on my plane.

Comment: Sorry this is not what I meant, come back to your previous subdivision, redo the alt shift S operation again, you should be able to have a circle

Comment: That's actually what I executed to get to the screenshot you see in the prior note. Starting to think I need to create a cube, execute it there, and then just connect it to my mesh... somehow.

Comment: Here is what I get with the exact same amount of vertices (12) and with alt shift S, is it not what you want? https://zupimages.net/up/20/38/ux02.jpg

Comment: Heh. That's what I want, but that's not what's happening in any of my attempts (on this mesh). Very much like my comment-image-link above, A whole axis of vertices do not change enough to create the circular arc. https://i.ibb.co/yfwsDKn/DEFORM-2020-09-16.png

Comment: please share this part of your file, use this site: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I can share a link to my Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1byBVHJzar58ErlVNMch_jo4OwhhYCngl/view?usp=sharing - You can select any of the external, square-ish facings as the Plane to try on.

Comment: I did try and it worked fine... I cannot reproduce this error.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> in *Object Mode* and *Apply Scale*.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error in the uploaded file - and I didn't even apply the scale.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I simply restarted blender and it started working fine. I use version 2.83.1 and not only with this, but with other actions too it has happened in the past. While I sculpt suddenly my draw brush won't add geometry. Restarting blender helps in that case as well.